# Function to join the first 2 elements from each list in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have this list of lists:

```
listoflist = [['BOTOS', 'AUGUSTIN', 14, 'March 2016', 600, 'ALOCATIA'], ['HENDRE', 'AUGUSTIN', 14, 'February 2015', 600, 'ALOCATIA']]
```

^^ That was just a example, I will have many more lists in my list of lists with the same format. 
This will be my desired output:

```
listoflist = [['BOTOS AUGUSTIN', 14, 'March 2016', 600, 'ALOCATIA'], ['HENDRE AUGUSTIN', 14, 'February 2015', 600, 'ALOCATIA']]
```

Basically in each list I want to join first index with the second to form a full name in one index like in the example.
And I would need a function for that who will take a input a list, how can  I do this in a simple way? (I don't want extra lib for this). I use python 3.5, thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate through the outer list and then join the slice of the first two items:

```
def merge_names(lst):
   for l in lst:
      l[0:2] = [' '.join(l[0:2])]

merge_names(listoflist)
print(listoflist)
# [['BOTOS AUGUSTIN', 14, 'March 2016', 600, 'ALOCATIA'], ['HENDRE AUGUSTIN', 14, 'February 2015', 600, 'ALOCATIA']]
```

Comment: why the downvote? this changes the original list in-place which is probably a good idea!

Comment: This works and it's exactly what I need, thank you sir! I have to accept your reply since was the fast one and correct!

Comment: Just a question, you don't need to return at the function end, I mean, return lst ?

Comment: @TatuBogdan Nope. I'm modifying the list in-place, so the original reference is still valid. Returning forces you to make an assignment to the output which could be a redundant name rebinding if you use the same name. OTOH, modifying the list in-place is faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

this simple list-comprehension should do the trick:

```
res = [[' '.join(item[0:2]), *item[2:]] for item in listoflist]
```

`join` the first two items in the list and append the rest as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
f = lambda *args: [' '.join(args[:2]), *args[2:]]

listoflist = [['BOTOS', 'AUGUSTIN', 14, 'March 2016', 600, 'ALOCATIA'], ['HENDRE', 'AUGUSTIN', 14, 'February 2015', 600, 'ALOCATIA']]

final_list = [f(*i) for i in listoflist]
```

Output:

```
[['BOTOS AUGUSTIN', 14, 'March 2016', 600, 'ALOCATIA'], ['HENDRE AUGUSTIN', 14, 'February 2015', 600, 'ALOCATIA']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension as well:

```
listoflist = [['BOTOS', 'AUGUSTIN', 14, 'March 2016', 600, 'ALOCATIA'], ['HENDRE', 'AUGUSTIN', 14, 'February 2015', 600, 'ALOCATIA']]

def f(lol):
  return [[' '.join(l[0:2])]+l[3:] for l in lol]

listoflist = f(listoflist)
print(listoflist)
# => [['BOTOS AUGUSTIN', 'March 2016', 600, 'ALOCATIA'], ['HENDRE AUGUSTIN', 'February 2015', 600, 'ALOCATIA']]
```